# AdView type in interface declaration

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I was trying to create an interface that uses property of type AdView. I tried the following code, but the AdView is unresolved. Not sure why, but I gotta feeling I did something stupid. How exactly does one use AdView in interfaces?

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public interface ActionResolver {

    public void showInterstitial();
    public void loadInterstitial();
    public AdView getBanner(); /// doesn't recognize AdView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have added the dependency correctly. There should not be anything special to use a class in an interface.

**build.gradle (excerpt)**

```
...
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    }
...
```